# Difference Between Azure Region pairs and Availability zones?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I understood both Azure regions and Availability Zones are meant for fail over. But is there any specific difference between these?

Answer (score 4):

Region pair are two regions nearby that are at least 300 miles away. Availability zones are inside region or can be between two region.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview.

> Azure availability zones are physically separate locations within each Azure region that are tolerant to local failures.

A region can contain multiple availability zones.
They protect against more local failures while the region pairs are further apart and protect from larger failures.